# when condition as per hostname in ansible task of azure devops pipeline

Tags: azure, ansible

Hostname usually look like vcs-200-01 . So when ever the hostname has vcs or vhs task should be run. I have tried below task but its running on all VMs instead of running on specific Vms

```
- name:Exceute shell script
  become:yes
  become_user:root
  become_method:sudo
  command: sh /usr/..../example.sh
  when:("'vcs' in inventory_hostname_short") or ("'vhs' in inventory_hostname_short")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the quotation of the logical expressions inside the parenthesis. These expressions are not evaluated but taken as strings. A not empty string evaluates to *True*. This is the reason the condition is always *True*.

```yaml
      when: ("'vcs' in inventory_hostname_short") or
            ("'vhs' in inventory_hostname_short")
```

The solution is simple. Remove the quotation. For example the task

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: inventory_hostname_short
      when: ('vcs' in inventory_hostname_short) or
            ('vhs' in inventory_hostname_short)
```

and the inventory

```sh
shell> cat hosts
vcs-200-01
vhs-200-01
vxs-200-01
```

give

```
ok: [vcs-200-01] => 
  inventory_hostname_short: vcs-200-01
ok: [vhs-200-01] => 
  inventory_hostname_short: vhs-200-01
skipping: [vxs-200-01]
```

---

The origin of this mistake might be YAML parser asking for a quotation. For example

```yaml
      when: 'vcs' in inventory_hostname_short
```

```
  ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  did not find expected key

The error appears to be in '/export/scratch/tmp/test-42.yml': line 10, column 19, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

        msg: vcs
      when: 'vcs' in inventory_hostname_short
                  ^ here
This one looks easy to fix. It seems that there is a value started
with a quote, and the YAML parser is expecting to see the line ended
with the same kind of quote. For instance:

    when: "ok" in result.stdout

Could be written as:

   when: '"ok" in result.stdout'

Or equivalently:

   when: "'ok' in result.stdout"
```

The recommended quotation fixes the problem

```yaml
      when: "'vcs' in inventory_hostname_short"  # OK
```

so does also the closing in parenthesis

```yaml
      when: ('vcs' in inventory_hostname_short)  # OK
```

but not both parenthesis and quotation

```yaml
      when: ("'vcs' in inventory_hostname_short")  # WRONG
```

---

The *or* expression

```yaml
      when: 'vcs' in inventory_hostname_short or
            'vhs' in inventory_hostname_short
```

will produce a similar error and the same recommendation

```
The offending line appears to be:

        var: inventory_hostname_short
      when: 'vcs' in inventory_hostname_short or
                  ^ here

Could be written as:

   when: '"ok" in result.stdout'

Or equivalently:

   when: "'ok' in result.stdout"
```

But here the recommended solution will not work and will produce the same error and the same recommendation

```yaml
      when: "'vcs' in inventory_hostname_short" or
            "'vhs' in inventory_hostname_short"
```

The logical expressions in *or* must be closed in parenthesis

```yaml
      when: ('vcs' in inventory_hostname_short) or
            ('vhs' in inventory_hostname_short)
```

Then the condition may be optionally quoted

```yaml
      when: "('vcs' in inventory_hostname_short) or
             ('vhs' in inventory_hostname_short)"
```